# How to destructur an array with this

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My linter is become crazy with this:

```
this.views = data.data[226];
```

What is the proper way of writing this using array destructuring?

Comment: you mean your linter is complaining about the magic number?

destructuring won't be able to help you retrieve the 227th element of an array _so easily_. you can just make 226 a constant and use that instead of using the number directly in the indexer.

Comment: There's no destructuring going on here. You're just assigning to a property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *really wanted to* use destructuring here, you would need 226 commas:

```js
const data = {
  data: Array.from({ length: 230 }, (_, i) => i)
};

const [,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,views1] = data.data;
console.log(views1);

// without destructuring:
const views2 = data.data[226];
console.log(views2);
```

But don't do that, it's unreadable - better to use standard bracket notation.

Destructuring extracts a *standalone variable* from the object or array in question - to assign the result to a property of some other object, you'll have to extract the info you want first, then assign it to the property you want. (eg `this.views = views1`) There isn't a shorter way to do it in one step, if the requirement is that you use destructuring in the process.

Comment: Did you actually count 226 commas?

Comment: @Idos I typed `','.repeat(226)` into the console and copied the string to the editor.

Comment: Dam, absolutely brilliant haha

Comment: @Idos he is "CertainPerformance", would've been performant to manually write 226 commas? :)